# Application Crash when using await Task.Run

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

My app is crashing at this line of code :

```
await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            bytes = page.AsPNG(72);
        });
```

My code :

```
public async Task<string> GetBitmaps(string filePath)
{

    //TODO -- WORK ON THIS
    PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(GetSeekableFileDescriptor(filePath));

    var appDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
    string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDirectory, "thumbnailsTemp", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));

    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (Stream resourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        resourceStream.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pdfRenderer.PageCount; i++)
    {
        TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.Page page = new TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.Page(stream, i);

        byte[] bytes = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            bytes = page.AsPNG(72);
        });

        using (FileStream output = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName + "Thumbnails" + i + ".png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

    return directoryPath;
}
```

I tried to use **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** but the **page.AsPNG(dpi)** method doesn't handle await.

***Update***

Here is the output message when Task.run is running :

And 1 min later if have the message : `"pdf.android isn't responding".`

> 03-13 20:46:19.862 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading reference 7 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 03-13 20:46:19.863
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref System.Collections[0xc69869c0] (asmctx
>   DEFAULT) -> System.Collections.dll[0xc91e0200]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.863
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Collections'
>   (System.Collections.dll) 03-13 20:46:19.863 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly System.Collections[0xc69869c0] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 03-13 20:46:19.863 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   'System.Collections.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "System.Collections.dll.so" not found 03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    (
>   4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Collections.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Collections.dll.config'. 03-13
>   20:46:19.864 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Collections/System.Collections.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Collections[0xc69869c0]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    (
>   4972): Loading reference 0 of System.Collections.dll asmctx DEFAULT,
>   looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0xc69869c0] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 53 03-13 20:46:19.864 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading
>   reference 6 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 03-13 20:46:19.864
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref System.Globalization[0xc6986960]
>   (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Globalization.dll[0xc91e1600]: 2 03-13
>   20:46:19.865 D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Globalization' (System.Globalization.dll) 03-13 20:46:19.865
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly System.Globalization[0xc6986960] added to
>   domain RootDomain, ref_count=1 03-13 20:46:19.865 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   AOT: image 'System.Globalization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library "System.Globalization.dll.so" not found 03-13 20:46:19.865
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Globalization.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:19.865 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Globalization.dll.config'. 03-13
>   20:46:19.865 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Globalization/System.Globalization.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:19.865 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Globalization[0xc6986960]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.866 D/Mono    (
>   4972): Loading reference 0 of System.Globalization.dll asmctx DEFAULT,
>   looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:19.866 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Globalization[0xc6986960] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 54 Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll
>   [External] Loaded assembly: System.Globalization.dll [External] 03-13
>   20:46:19.888 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading reference 4 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 03-13 20:46:19.888
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref System.Threading[0xc6986900] (asmctx
>   DEFAULT) -> System.Threading.dll[0xc91e1b00]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.888
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Threading'
>   (System.Threading.dll) 03-13 20:46:19.888 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly
>   System.Threading[0xc6986900] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
>   03-13 20:46:19.889 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   'System.Threading.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "System.Threading.dll.so" not found 03-13 20:46:19.889 D/Mono    (
>   4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Threading.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:19.889 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Threading.dll.config'. 03-13 20:46:19.889
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Threading/System.Threading.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:19.889 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Threading[0xc6986900]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.889 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Loading reference 0 of System.Threading.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking
>   for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:19.890 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Threading[0xc6986900] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 55 03-13 20:46:19.890 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading
>   reference 8 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 03-13 20:46:19.890
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref System.Text.Encoding[0xc69868a0]
>   (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Text.Encoding.dll[0xc76c5000]: 2 03-13
>   20:46:19.890 D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Text.Encoding' (System.Text.Encoding.dll) 03-13 20:46:19.890
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly System.Text.Encoding[0xc69868a0] added to
>   domain RootDomain, ref_count=1 Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll
>   [External]03-13 20:46:19.890 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   'System.Text.Encoding.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "System.Text.Encoding.dll.so" not found
>
> 03-13 20:46:19.891 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Text.Encoding.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:19.891 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Text.Encoding.dll.config'. 03-13
>   20:46:19.891 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Text.Encoding/System.Text.Encoding.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:19.891 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Text.Encoding[0xc69868a0]: 2 03-13 20:46:19.891 D/Mono    (
>   4972): Loading reference 0 of System.Text.Encoding.dll asmctx DEFAULT,
>   looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:19.891 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Text.Encoding[0xc69868a0] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 56 Loaded assembly: System.Text.Encoding.dll
>   [External] 03-13 20:46:20.007 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading reference 5
>   of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Runtime.Extensions,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   03-13 20:46:20.007 D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref
>   System.Runtime.Extensions[0xc6986c60] (asmctx DEFAULT) ->
>   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll[0xc76c6400]: 2 03-13 20:46:20.007 D/Mono
>   ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions'
>   (System.Runtime.Extensions.dll) 03-13 20:46:20.007 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly System.Runtime.Extensions[0xc6986c60] added to domain
>   RootDomain, ref_count=1 03-13 20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT:
>   image 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library "System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so" not found 03-13
>   20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.config'. 03-13
>   20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Extensions/System.Runtime.Extensions.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Runtime.Extensions[0xc6986c60]: 2 03-13 20:46:20.008 D/Mono
>   ( 4972): Loading reference 0 of System.Runtime.Extensions.dll asmctx
>   DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:20.008 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0xc6986c60] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 57 Loaded assembly:
>   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External] Thread started:
>
> ## 2 Thread started:  #3 Thread started:  #4 Thread started:  #5 03-13 20:46:26.407 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>
> Loading reference 1 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065 03-13 20:46:26.407
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] -> Mono.Android[0xe9cccd40]:
>   44 03-13 20:46:26.850 D/Mono    ( 4972): DllImport searching in:
>   '**Internal' ('(null)'). 03-13 20:46:26.850 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'. 03-13 20:46:26.850
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'. 03-13
>   20:46:26.850 D/Mono    ( 4972): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'. 03-13 20:46:26.854 D/Mono    (
>   4972): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)'). 03-13
>   20:46:26.854 D/Mono    ( 4972): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'. 03-13 20:46:26.854 D/Mono
>   ( 4972): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'. 03-13
>   20:46:26.854 D/Mono    ( 4972): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'. 03-13 20:46:26.857 D/Mono
>   ( 4972): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)'). 03-13
>   20:46:26.857 D/Mono    ( 4972): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'. 03-13 20:46:26.857 D/Mono
>   ( 4972): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'. 03-13
>   20:46:26.857 D/Mono    ( 4972): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_get_byte_array_region'. 03-13 20:46:27.053 D/skia
>   ( 4972): --- Failed to create image decoder with message
>   'unimplemented' 03-13 20:46:27.127 I/companyname.pd( 4972): Explicit
>   concurrent copying GC freed 16071(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(100KB)
>   LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 639us total 6.952ms 03-13
>   20:46:27.131 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 369 objects 9865
>   opaque 2897 colors 364 colors-bridged 364 colors-visible 364 xref 8
>   cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.03ms tarjan 1.13ms
>   scc-setup 0.05ms gather-xref 0.02ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 1.70ms
>   03-13 20:46:27.131 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running
>   for 12.47ms 03-13 20:46:27.131 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_MINOR: (Nursery
>   full) time 5.12ms, stw 6.23ms promoted 1312K major size: 2240K in use:
>   1560K los size: 3072K in use: 2386K 03-13 20:46:27.158 D/skia    (
>   4972): --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
>   03-13 20:46:27.187 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading reference 13 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.__override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Text.Encoding.Extensions,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   03-13 20:46:27.187 D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions[0xe9d426e0] (asmctx DEFAULT) ->
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll[0xc5db8900]: 2 03-13 20:46:27.187
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly
>   'System.Text.Encoding.Extensions'
>   (System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll) Loaded assembly:
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]03-13 20:46:27.187
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions[0xe9d426e0] added to domain
>   RootDomain, ref_count=1
>
> 03-13 20:46:27.188 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   'System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.so" not found 03-13
>   20:46:27.188 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:27.188 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:27.188 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:27.189 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions[0xe9d426e0]: 2 03-13 20:46:27.189
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading reference 0 of
>   System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:27.189 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Text.Encoding.Extensions[0xe9d426e0] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 58 03-13 20:46:27.233 D/Mono    ( 4972): Loading
>   reference 12 of
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.pdf/files/.**override**/TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer.dll
>   asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 03-13 20:46:27.233
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Image addref System.Reflection[0xe9d43640] (asmctx
>   DEFAULT) -> System.Reflection.dll[0xc76c9b00]: 2 03-13 20:46:27.233
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Reflection'
>   (System.Reflection.dll) 03-13 20:46:27.233 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly
>   System.Reflection[0xe9d43640] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
>   03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972): AOT: image
>   'System.Reflection.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "System.Reflection.dll.so" not found 03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    (
>   4972): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Reflection.dll.so'
>   not found: (null) 03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config
>   attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.dll.config'. 03-13
>   20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/sdks/out/android-x86-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection/System.Reflection.config'.
>   03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972): Assembly Ref addref
>   TallComponents.PDF.Rasterizer[0xe9ccb780] ->
>   System.Reflection[0xe9d43640]: 2 03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Loading reference 0 of System.Reflection.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking
>   for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 03-13 20:46:27.234 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection[0xe9d43640] ->
>   mscorlib[0xe9ccb420]: 59 Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.dll
>   [External] 03-13 20:46:27.513 I/companyname.pd( 4972): Explicit
>   concurrent copying GC freed 1556(87KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(6MB) LOS
>   objects, 50% free, 1997KB/3MB, paused 632us total 6.975ms 03-13
>   20:46:27.513 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 3 objects 3
>   opaque 0 colors 3 colors-bridged 3 colors-visible 3 xref 0 cache-hit 0
>   cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.03ms tarjan 0.02ms scc-setup
>   0.02ms gather-xref 0.02ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.16ms 03-13 20:46:27.513 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for
>   7.78ms 03-13 20:46:27.513 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_MINOR: (Concurrent start) time 1.03ms, stw 3.77ms promoted 126K major size: 2368K in use:
>   1719K los size: 16856K in use: 16154K 03-13 20:46:27.514 D/Mono    (
>   4972): GC_MAJOR_CONCURRENT_START: (LOS overflow) 03-13 20:46:27.643
>   I/companyname.pd( 4972): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed
>   505(41KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1971KB/3MB,
>   paused 627us total 6.512ms 03-13 20:46:27.644 D/Mono    ( 4972):
>   GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 205 objects 1700 opaque 503 colors 200
>   colors-bridged 200 colors-visible 200 xref 6 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit
>   0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.03ms tarjan 0.46ms scc-setup 0.04ms gather-xref
>   0.02ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.03ms 03-13 20:46:27.644 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 8.50ms 03-13 20:46:27.644
>   D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_MAJOR_CONCURRENT_FINISH: (finishing) time
>   131.48ms, stw 4.30ms los size: 2048K in use: 606K 03-13 20:46:27.644 D/Mono    ( 4972): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 2704K in use: 1634K
>   Thread finished:  #4 Le thread 0x4 s'est arrêté avec le
>   code 0 (0x0). Thread finished:  #5 Le thread 0x5 s'est
>   arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0). Thread finished:  #3 Thread
>   started:  #6 Thread started:  #7 Le thread
>   0x3 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0). Thread finished:
>
> ## 2 Thread started:  #8 Le thread 0x2 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).

Comment: what is the exception causing the crash?

Comment: I don't have any errors... my app is just freezing, I have a fixed screen corresponding to the current page where I was calling this method.

Comment: you specifically said "crash" - have you tried using a try/catch to find the root cause?  Have you looked at the console/logs for any helpful output?

Comment: Hi , have a check with OutPut of Visual Studio wehther exists detail error info there . If so you can share here .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  Update done with the output message

Comment: While it is legitimate to ask here, it is not a good idea as your app crashes while executing on the 3rd party paid library - most people here won't have idea what it is and it is paid so you should have paid support there.